# Подключиться к локальному порту с докера

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, docker-compose

На centos локально запущен mysql и установлен веб сервер в docker compose с ubuntu 14.04. Каким образом я могу подключиться с докера к локально запущеному на сервере mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я делал подобное с `postgresql`, нужно:

1. настроить `docker` так чтобы bridge который он делает по умолчанию `docker0`
   имел наперед известный `ip` адрес `172.17.42.1` (не помню подробностей, но возможно так docker настроен по умолчанию?)
2. прописать в конфиге чтобы `mysqld` слушал `172.17.42.1` 
   с помощью `bind-address=`
3. Убедиться что `mysqld` стартует позже `docker` - это зависит от того что использует в системе. У меня был `init.d + upstart`, поэтому я просто добавил цикл на `bash` типа `ifconfig | grep docker0`
4. Возможно поправить правила `iptables` чтобы он пакеты не рубил (если настройки не параноидальные, то обычно этот шаг не нужен)

Все теперь из контейнера можно обрашаться по адресу `172.17.42.1` к `mysql`

Answer (score 0):

довольно элегантным решением можно считать [монтирование socket-файла, создаваемого *mysqld*, внутрь контейнера](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30484147/4827341):

```
$ docker run ... -v /путь/на/хосте/к/mysqld.sock:/путь/в/контейнере/к/mysqld.sock ...
```

или, раз вы используете `docker compose`, с помощью соответствующих строк в compose-файле.

путь можно, например, «подсмотреть» в конфигурации *mysqld*:

```
$ grep -r socket /etc/mysql*
```

Comment: Спасибо. Отличный способ. Но он мне не совсем подходит так как в данном случае мне нужен доступ не только к mysql